# Generator Function not being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is my api not being called when I define my get function as a generator function?

This works:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('this works');
});
```

This also works:

```
router.get('/', get);

function get(req, res){
   res.send('works!');
}
```

This does not work:

```
router.get('/', get);

function* get(req, res){
   res.send('does not work!');
}
```

Rest of the file...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//setting up the get route as above

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you tried: `router.get('/', yield get);`?

Comment: I don't think express works with generator functions. You cannot just replace a normal function with a generator function. The consumer of the function must also understand that it gets a generator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koa is built to work with generators so you may have more luck with that.

Comment: Went this route instead of using express.